# How to retrieve descendants using Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml, xml-namespaces

I have an xml in which I'm looping through every `node` and in that I want to retrieve `xhtml` elements and I tried

```
foreach (XElement element in xdoc.Descendants(namespace))
{
  var result = element.Descendants(namespace + "xhtml")
}
```

but the enumeration is always returning `empty`

Data :

```
<namespace xmlns="http://www.find.org/schemas/">
  <date>2015</date>
  <xhtml:link xmlns:xhtml="xhtml:link" rel="alternate" />
  <xhtml:link xmlns:xhtml="xhtml:link" rel="alternate" />
  <xhtml:link xmlns:xhtml="xhtml:link" rel="alternate" />
</namespace>
```

Comment: You have not posted the namespace for `xhtml` there must be a namespace defined for it like `xmlns:xhtml:"http://foo"`

Comment: @Rahul Singh I didn't get you,can you post a samplr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link elements are in its own namespace, called `xhtml` in the namespace `xhtml:link`. You need to use that to select the elements.

```
 // namespace of yout document
 var ns = (XNamespace) "http://www.find.org/schemas"; 
 // namespace of link elements
 var nsXhtml = (XNamespace) "xhtml:link";

 var result = xdoc.Root.Elements(nsXhtml+ "link");
 result.Dump();
```

In an xml document you should be on the lookout for `xmlns:` constructs and those can be at the top or defined on an element. Using no or the wrong namespace will not find your elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
                "<namespace xmlns=\"http://www.find.org/schemas/\">" +
                  "<date>2015</date>" +
                  "<xhtml:link xmlns:xhtml=\"xhtml:link\" rel=\"alternate\" />" +
                  "<xhtml:link xmlns:xhtml=\"xhtml:link\" rel=\"alternate\" />" +
                  "<xhtml:link xmlns:xhtml=\"xhtml:link\" rel=\"alternate\" />" +
                "</namespace>";

            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(input);

            List<XElement> links = xdoc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "link").ToList();
        }
    }
}​
```